# Добавление данных в listView основываясь на классе

Tags: java, mysql, javafx, listview

Пытаюсь реализовать заполнение listView основываясь на данных полученных из БД.

Знаю, что можно выполнить заполнение как примитивно listView.getItems().add()

Так и через ObservableList.

но суть вопроса в том, что данные из бд я выгрузил в класс, который эмитирует структуру таблицы.

Требуется, чтобы я поместил в listView этот массив, отображалось только поле name этого класса, а когда вызывалось событие selection(ну или как оно там) я мог обратиться к другому полю этого класс, к примеру id, чтобы построить следующий sql запрос.

ResultSet rc = mc.getData("SELECT id, name, rate, min, typetime FROM contributions");
            ObservableList list = new ObservableList() {...};

```
        while(rc.next()) {
            Contributions contributions = new Contributions();
            System.out.println(rc.getString(2));
            contributions.id = rc.getInt(1);
            contributions.name = rc.getString(2);
            contributions.rate = rc.getInt(3);
            contributions.min = rc.getInt(4);
            contributions.typetime = rc.getInt(5);
            list.add(contributions);

        }
```

Comment: В чем собственно вопрос, как заполнять listView, чтобы я потом при событии выбора какого-либо элемента пользователем, мог запросить поле id из класса хранящего данные из бд. На основе класса создан ObservableList.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        ListView<Entity> listView = new ListView<>(mockSelect());
        listView.setCellFactory(param -> new EntityCell());
        listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(this::selectEntity);
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(listView));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    // реакция на выбор в списке
    void selectEntity(ObservableValue<? extends Entity> observable, Entity oldValue, Entity newValue) {
        // вывод в консоль ИД выбранной сущности
        System.out.println(newValue == null ? null : newValue.id);
    }

    // имитация загрузки данных из БД
    ObservableList<Entity> mockSelect() {
        return FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Entity(1L, "First"),
                new Entity(2L, "Second")
        );
    }

    // сущность базы данных
    private static class Entity {
        Long id;
        String name;

        public Entity(Long id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }

    // отобажение определенного поля сущности базы данных в списке
    private static class EntityCell extends ListCell<Entity> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Entity item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);
            setText(empty || item == null ? null : item.name);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: А listView можно создавать только динамически?

Comment: Вопрос не понятен. Но предположительно: Вы так же можете его взять из `fxml`, с указанием generic типа в контроллере.